# Python multiline comments

Tags: python, comments

I am struggling with multi line comments in Python, I understood I can use `#` at the start of every line of multi line comments but there is also another way of using `"""` at the start and end of the comment; however, in my interpreter the `"""` method gives an output instead of ignoring the comment.

```
>>> """this should
be a multi
line comment"""
```

And my interpreter gives the following output:

```
'this should\nbe a multi\nline comment'
```

Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Triple quoted strings are used as comments by many developers but it is actually not a comment. It is similar to regular strings in python but it allows the string to be multi-line. You will find no official reference for triple quoted strings to be a comment.

In python, there is only one type of comment that starts with hash `#` and can contain only a single line of text.

According to [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), it can however be used as a docstring, which is again not really a comment.

```py
def foo():
    """
    Developer friendly text for describing the purpose of function
    Some test cases used by different unit testing libraries
    """
   <body of the function>
```

You can just assign them to a variable as you do with single quoted strings:

```py
x = """a multi-line text
enclosed by
triple quotes
"""
```

Furthermore, if you try it in a repl, triple quoted strings get printed, had it really been a comment, should it have been printed?:

```py
>>> #comment
>>> """triple quoted"""
'triple quoted'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, i found this website along with others which said that triple quoted strings can act as comments, could you verify if the website is wrong or is it me who misunderstood it?

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_comments.asp

Comment: You should be aware that w3schools generally has a dubious reputation. But they actually explain that this is a string constant and that using it for comments is a bit of a hack.

Comment: @AryanBansal I have already mentioned in the answer *You will find no official reference for triple quoted strings to be a comment.* To act as comment doesn't mean its comment, and w3schools isn't the official site to look at.

Comment: +1 for this - *if you try it in a repl, triple quoted strings get printed, had it really been a comment, should it have been printed ?*

Comment: @ThePyGuy Thanks for the reply, but even on geeksforgeeks it stated that:
Python ignores the string literals that are not assigned to a variable so we can use these string literals as a comment.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-comments/
I even copy pasted the exact code but still my interpreter does not ignore the triple quoted string

Comment: @AryanBansal, even geeksforgeeks is  not an official site to look at, furthermore, it also clearly mentions that **Python does not provide the option for multiline comments. However, there are different ways through which we can write multiline comments.** under the multiline comment section.

Comment: Ok ok so I made some progress.
When I copy pasted the code in pycharm it worked, but in python interpreter it didn't, could you be so kind to explain why this is like this?

Comment: @AryanBansal, if you want, you can also take a look at [PEP 8 style guide for comments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments)

Comment: @AryanBansal I think I see your confusion. If you type `5` into the interpreter, it will output `5`. If you type "a", it will output """a""". However, if you type `"""this should be ignored"""; x=5;print(x)`, it will ignore the string and just print 5, because it's not assigned to anything, and there is a command in the rest of the line. This is just an idiosyncrasy of i/o in an interactive shell. The same way you can do quick math in the shell, `5+6` will output `11` for example

Comment: @G. Anderson thanks for helping I think I understood now.

Answer (score -1):

This is very easy to accomplish in python.

```
# This is a single-line comment

'''
This is a multi-line comment
'''
```

Just put the comments in ''' and put whatever you want inside of them!